# How to add wordpress to nuxtjs in a subpage

Tags: wordpress, vue.js, nuxt.js, subdirectory, nuxtjs2

I have project in nuxtjs 2 and it’s deployed on vercel. I have also a web server where I use for wordpress site. Is it possible to add wordpress woocommerce  store to nuxtjs. I mean I want on my main website on nuxt I wanna have path like example.com/shop and on that path I want have my woocommerce shop. How can I do it in nuxt. Is anyone can help me

I heard that in wordpress you can set a path where it should be shown.

Answer (score 2):

You can show your products from WooCommerce in your Nuxt app by getting the products over a WooCommerce REST API:

- https://woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-rest-api/
- https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#list-all-products

Or over a GraphQL endpoint using this extension:

- https://github.com/wp-graphql/wp-graphql-woocommerce

You might also want to check out this project https://woonuxt.com/